# Cannot build CMake project from YAML

Tags: cmake, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to create a build pipeline using a YAML file on Azure DevOps. The *azure-pipelines.yml* file is fairly simple:

```yml
resources:
- repo: self

queue:
  name: Hosted VS2017
  demands: cmake
```

The build fails immediately, though, with the following error message:

> ```
> ##[Error 1]
> No agent found in pool Hosted VS2017 which satisfies the specified demands:
>      cmake
>      Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.140.2
> ```

The `Agent.Version` is reported as `2.140.2` on the requested pool, so that's causing the check to fail. I'm not sure where this requirement is picked up, as I didn't specify it. I can work around the issue by explicitly adding an `Agent.Version` check:

```yml
queue:
  name: Hosted VS2017
  demands: cmake Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.140.1
```

Although I'm unsure about the implications, and I'd much rather understand, what the core issue is. The questions are:

- Why is the `Agent.Version` check added?
- Is there anything I can do to fix the build issue?

Comment: May be the `cmake` is not available in the Hosted VS2017 agent?

Comment: @jay: CMake is available in the Hosted VS2017 agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hosted 2017 Agent do support cmake, but cmake is not added in the Agent Capabilities. So you'd either remove the cmake demand from the build definition or add cmake in Agent Capabilities as below:
[image]

Comment: This solves the issue, but I'm not sure, why. What's the relevance of the value "q" in the "cmake" user capability? Why does this solve the issue? And where was the  Agent.Version check picked up previously? Also, why doesn't this simply work out-of-the box? It's not like I authored the YAML script myself. It was generated by Azure DevOps off of a pipeline created using the designer.

Comment: @IInspectable It could be any string instead of "q" since your demand is just "cmake" exists rather than "cmake" equals "q". Some tasks required specified agent version but some does not. If you added a task required specified agent version, the agent version demand will be added automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I guess that makes sense now. With one exception: Why did the `cmake` demand require a future `Agent.Version`? If you can, please incorporate the additional information from your previous comment into this answer to make it self-contained.

Comment: @IInspectable 2.140.2 was released one month ago and it is the latest version installed on Hosted Agent.

Comment: I understand that, but the introduced version check uses *"greater than"* (as opposed to *"greater or equal"*). That check requires a future version of the build agent. With the documentation available, I have no way of knowing, whether this is intentional or a bug.

Comment: @IInspectable -gtVersion is the minimum version, include equals and greater than. Since for your self-hosted agent, you may installed more new version than 2.140.2.

Comment: If that were the case, the check described in the question wouldn't fail, and wouldn't be fixed when adding an explicit check with a lower version either. `-gtVersion` does indeed mean *"greater than"*, not *"greater or equal"*. If that's not the case, I would welcome documentation explaining otherwise. I wasn't able to find any official documentation on this.

Comment: @IInspectable It was failed since cmake didn't not exist in the capability, not the agent version. I tested it at my side, Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.140.1 also get the same error. Can you check that?

Comment: I tested `demands: cmake Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.140.1`, **without** adding the `cmake` user capability, and that succeeded for me (on the VS2017 Hosted Agent 2.140.2).